# Creating Leaflet layers via function

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I have a few dozens layers to create, and right now I'm doing it with (horribly ugly) duplicated code.
I'm sure there's a way to just do it in a function (and call that multiple times), but I couldn't figure out how to get it done (I'm pretty new to Leaflet).

Here's what my current code looks like:

```
var aaa = L.geoJson(null, {
      pointToLayer: function(feature, latlng) {
        var marker = L.circleMarker(latlng);
        marker.setStyle({weight: 1});
        return marker;
      }
    })
    $.getJSON("json/AAA.json", function(data) {
      aaa.addData(data);
    });
```

How would I squeeze this into a function, so I could do this:

```
makeLayer('aaa');
makeLayer('bbb');
function makeLayer(name) {
   ???
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) to construct the path to the JSON based on a name. If you need the value of the resulting layer, you can use `return` to pass back the result of the function.

```js
function makeLayer(name) {
  var newLayer = L.geoJson(null, {
    pointToLayer: function(feature, latlng) {
      var marker = L.circleMarker(latlng);
      marker.setStyle({weight: 1});
      return marker;
    }
  });
  $.getJSON(`json/${name}.json`, function(data) {
    newLayer.addData(data);
  });
  return newLayer;
}

var aaa = makeLayer('aaa');
var bbb = makeLayer('bbb');
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked perfectly!
I was so fixated on somehow solving this via "evals" that I overlooked the simple & elegant function returns...